# Issues when installing vanilla gnome on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: gnome, 21.10

I am seeing this issue when installing the vanilla Gnome on Ubuntu 21.10. I have no idea how to fix this or revert this install. These errors are shown every time I have to install/upgrade something.

```
Setting up vanilla-gnome-default-settings (20.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gdm3-theme.gresource
dpkg: error processing package vanilla-gnome-default-settings (--configure):
 installed vanilla-gnome-default-settings package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 vanilla-gnome-default-settings
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 9):

Ran into the same issue. There seems to be some naming changes that result in this problem. The mailing list did [provide an answer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-gnome-default-settings/+bug/1935767/comments/3):

> I have a manual fix for this.
>
> Edit "`/var/lib/dpkg/info/vanilla-gnome-default-settings.postinst`"
>
> Change "`gdm3-theme.gresource`" to "`gdm-theme.gresource`"
>
> Then "`sudo apt install -f`"
>
> The vanilla gnome setup now works as expected.

I can confirm this worked for me!

Comment: This workaround works just fine. Thank you. Here it as a single command line: `sudo sed -i "s/gdm3-theme.gresource/gdm-theme.gresource/g" /var/lib/dpkg/info/vanilla-gnome-default-settings.postinst; sudo apt install -f`