# How do I Install Ubuntu, using BtrFS and the Server ISO and still be able to use Timeshift?

Tags: server, partitioning, gnome, btrfs, timeshift

To be clear, I'm not trying to install a **server**; I'm using it to install the **base OS** and then I install the [vanilla gnome desktop package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/vanilla-gnome-desktop).  I use the **server ISO** because they stopped making the **mini ISO** after v18.04.

I've been poking at this most of the afternoon in a VM.  Steps I currently take:

1. Run through the *server* install process...
2. Create an EFI boot partition
3. The rest of it gets mounted as root (/) and formatted BtrFS.
4. Reboot and then install *vanilla gnome*: `sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop`
5. [Get around the strange bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370504/) when installing the aforementioned package.
6. Install **Timeshift**: `sudo apt install timeshift`

After a reboot, I log in and find that **Timeshift** nags about not having **subvolumes** it can use.  I poked around the web and found what looked like a [simple fix](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=265643) but either I'm missing something or it just doesn't apply to this OS.

Now, I can use the **Desktop** installation disk and I can do a custom partitioning setup, via the GUI, where I basically do the same thing as above.  I create two partitions: one for the EFI boot partition and one formatted BtrFS and set to mount as root.  However, I install via the GUI, reboot, install Timeshift and everything is fine.  When you look at the drive, all you see are two folders on the root of it: one is **@** and the other is **@home**.  Evidently, Timeshift likes that setup and folder structure better.  I don't like the default Ubuntu desktop environment and removing it is messy so that's why I like using the server installation media.

So, how does one recreate the process, that's seemingly *automagically* used by the Desktop version's GUI install process, via the *server* installation media?

Answer (score 0):

The following is lifted from the teejeetech website.

https://teejeetech.com/timeshift/

> Supported System Configurations

> BTRFS – OS installed on BTRFS volumes (with or without LUKS)

> Only Ubuntu-type layouts with @ and @home subvolumes are supported

> @ and @home subvolumes may be on same or different BTRFS volumes

> @ may be on BTRFS volume and /home may be mounted on non-BTRFS partition

> Other layouts are not supported

That suggests to me that if you simply create those subvolumes you will be good to go. Have a look here: [Creating btrfs subvolume like @ or @home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331233/creating-btrfs-subvolume-like-or-home)

Comment: Thanks for the intel; I'll have a look and test in a VM.

Comment: I have come across that post before.  I created those folders (@, @home) but I think I needed to move the existing root (/) into the `@` folder.  When I logged in, it acted like my profile had never been set up so I think that was something I missed.  FSTAB was set to mount `@home` as /home but I never moved my existing profile into the `@home` folder.  I'm going to see what I can do in a VM.

Comment: This might help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNnfrKa6fLQ